# Rename csv columns according to the choosen dropdown list in streamlit in python

Tags: python, csv, streamlit

I am using `pandas` and `streamlit` to rename the columns of the csv. And I am new to python. How can I do it in streamlit/python? In JS it can be done via mapping and updating the object. But I wan't to achieve it in python/streamlit.

`df.rename(columns={'Name': 'Name', 'Address1': 'Address_1','Address2': 'Address_2','Address3': 'Address_3','Address4': 'Address_4'}, inplace=True)`

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILW9D.png)

[Desire Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs3ef.png)

Comment: Try using `st.selectbox` and `st.text_input`, create a dictionary and then use it in the `df.rename`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


def main():

    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv", sep=",", index_col=False)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "Name": ["Joe", "John", "Jane", "Mary"],
            "Address1": ["A", "E", "I", "M"],
            "Address2": ["B", "F", "J", "N"],
            "Address3": ["C", "G", "K", "O"],
            "Address4": ["D", "H", "L", "P"],
            "City": ["Dublin", "Ontario", "London", "Paris"],
            "Country": ["Ireland", "Canada", "England", "France"],
        })

    st.dataframe(df)

    with st.form(key="form"):
        col_to_change = st.selectbox("Column to change", df.columns)
        new_col_name = st.text_input("New name", value="")
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

    if submit_button:
        df = df.rename(columns={col_to_change: new_col_name})

    st.dataframe(df)

    df.to_csv("my_csv.csv", sep=",", index=False)

    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It reads and saves to a file called `mycsv.csv`. This csv can be missing at the beginning.

This snippet of code lets the user choose a column and a new name, then click on a button to rename the column of the dataframe and save it to `mycsv.csv` with the new column name:

```py
    with st.form(key="form"):
        col_to_change = st.selectbox("Column to change", df.columns)
        new_col_name = st.text_input("New name", value="")
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

    if submit_button:
        df = df.rename(columns={col_to_change: new_col_name})
```

Comment: It works but I want to list the column headers at the left of the table and on the right is a dropdown of  the new name of the column header.